# Node.js & Redis / hget synchronize

Tags: node.js, redis

I wish to create a synchronize command of hget in node.js.

I wrote the following:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
var res1 = dbclient.hget("all_records", "/" + full_path)
if (res1 != undefined){
    objStatus.status = "TRUE"
 } else {
     objStatus.status = "FALSE"
 }
```

The problem is that in `res1`, I always gets `true`, while I set numbers to this field:

```
dbclient.hset("all_records", key, size); // size is number
```

It also returns true if the key doesn't exists.

How can I perform this command?

Edit (here is the full code and why I use sync call):

```
   for (var attr in paths) {
        var full_path = "/0" + attr
        var objStatus = new Object();
        var res1 = dbclient.hget("all_records", "/" + full_path)
        if (res1 != undefined){
            objStatus.status = "TRUE"
        } else {
            objStatus.status = "FALSE"
        }
     }
     arrayResult.push(objStatus);
    }
    return arrayResult;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is problematic;

```
var res1 = dbclient.hget("all_records", "/" + full_path)
```

the call to `hget` does not return the value, it calls back to a given callback (which you omitted) when the value has been fetched;

```
dbclient.hget("all_records", "/" + full_path, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

...would print the value of your key.

Comment: But this is async call. In the full code, I iterate over all the records, and just then return the result to the client. If I use your suggest, then I will return an empty array - because it will not wait for all the hget to be completed.

Comment: I edit the question. With your suggestion, `arrayResult` will return empty.

Comment: @MiddleWare It's not really my suggestion, it's the way this Redis API works. You'll most likely have to make your function async with a callback or promise to be able to pass the populated array to the calling code in a straight forward manner.

Answer (score 0):

co + co-redis can run it synchronously

```
var co = require('co');
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient();
var wrapper = require('co-redis');
var redisCo = wrapper(redisClient);
co(function* () {
  var res1 = yield redisCo.hget("all_records", "/" + full_path)
  if (res1 != undefined){
     objStatus.status = "TRUE"
  } else {
     objStatus.status = "FALSE"
  }
});
```