# Fetching synchroneously from redis in Node through async/await

Tags: javascript, express, redis

I am learning Javascript and Vue from Java from few days and not able to solve a problem with my Node, Express app through async/await. The below code is receiving a list of Stock symbols from request and then checking through a loop if details against any of the symbols is already cached in redis.

```
var controllers = {
   getCurrentPrice: function(req, res) {
        var symbolsArray = req.body.symbols;
        var results = [];
        var tmpArray = [];

        _(symbolsArray).each( async function(symbol, iPos) {
            client.hget("realtime", symbol, function(err, reply)    {
                if(reply)   {
                    await results.push(reply);
                } else  {
                    await tmpArray.push(symbol);
                }
                console.log("reply", reply);
            });
        });
        console.log("Results so far ", results);
        if( !tmpArray || tmpArray.length == 0 ) { //will be fetching these now }
    }
}
```

Getting output in the inner console statement but not for the outer one. I have tried looking at few solutions through net like through redis-co to promisify the redis calls but could not exactly solve it.

Comment: Probably is that your promises are failing, have you tried adding `.catch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

1. Doing `await` on the result of a `.push()` doesn't do anything useful.  You use `await` on a promise.
2. Your `.each()` loop doesn't wait for each asycnhronous operation to finish, therefore you have no way of knowing when all the async operations are done

I'd suggest using a regular `for` loop where `async/await` will pause for the loop:

```
const util = require('util');
client.hgetP = util.promisify(client.hget);

var controllers = {
   getCurrentPrice: async function(req, res) {
        var symbolsArray = req.body.symbols;
        var results = [];
        var tmpArray = [];

        for (let symbol of symbolsArray) {
            let reply = await client.hgetP("realtime", symbol);
            if (reply) {
                results.push(reply);
            } else {
                tempArray.push(symbol);
            }
        }

        // do any further processing of tempArray here

        console.log(results);
        return results;    // this will be the resolved value of the returned promise
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
obj.getCurrentPrice.then(results => {
     console(results);
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. The other problem in the Redis call I could resolve through co-redis as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536710/node-js-redis-hget-synchronize

Comment: @RajMalhotra - If this answers your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.